# Sorting on several columns in Cassandra

Tags: sorting, cassandra, nosql

Is it possible to sort on several columns in Cassandra?

For example, with this table :

```
CREATE TABLE playlists (
  id uuid,
  artist text,
  album text,
  title text,
  song_order int,
  song_id uuid,
  realese_date timestamp,
  tags text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((id),song_order))
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (song_order ASC);
```

I want to sort by id, artists, album, title, song_id, release_date, tags separately. I already read this question [Order By any fields in Cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30418185/order-by-any-field-in-cassandra?newreg=434d25631d3843cca1d02d8202a24547), but is it the best practice to replicate the table as many times as the number of columns that I want to sort?

I have also noticed the materialized view feature, but with that approach I can't add SASI indexes to filter the table.